# How can I change log4j behaviour when it formats parameters in a log line?

Tags: log4j

Log4j allows to specify the log string and the objects separately. For example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyLogger {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogger.class);

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        logger.info("This is a number {} and this is a string {}", 5, "blah!");
    }
}
```

results in this output

```
This is a number 5 and this is a string blah!
```

I'd like to know if I can tell log4j to print all the parameters surrounded by quotes every time it prints a log line . So the same piece of code above:

```
logger.info("This is a number {} and this is a string {}", 5, "blah!");
```

would output:

```
This is a number "5" and this is a string "blah!"
```

What I want to do is changing log4j behaviour, not the call to the logger method (logger.info(...)). My problem is that I'm calling the logger in thousands of places and changing all the calls isn't practical.

Comment: please show the code.what you want and what you have tried?

Comment: I changed the description of the question trying to be clearer.

Comment: you may use it like this  -- >                                                              logger.info("This is a number {} and this is a string {}", "'5'", "'blah!'");

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add quotes with escape character i.e. `\` either in the original string before and after the parameter brackets or in the arguments itself if it is string. Below are the examples;

1. `logger.info("args one \"{}\" and two \"{}\"", "blah!!", 4);` will output `args one "blah!!" and two "4"`.
2. `logger.info("args one {} and two {}", "\"blah!!\"", 4);` will output `args one "blah!!" and two 4`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you reply but the problem was not escaping the quotes. I will edit my post being more precise. What I want to do is changing something (I don't know what :( ) in log4j in order to change the behaviour of the logger in order to change the behaviour so that I don't need to change my code (I'm calling the logger in thousands of places)  to change all my log lines